find the button with a specific aria-label attribute
I would like to use Selenium to click on a button on a Linkedln web page to activate the "Easy Apply" filter. I want to find a button with a specific aria-label attribute and at the same time use Linkedln's Easy Apply feature.
The following HTML element represents the button to activate the "Easy Apply" filter:
<li class="search-reusables__primary-filter search-reusables__primary-filter--hidden">
  <div class="search-reusables__filter-binary-toggle">
    <button aria-checked="false" role="radio" aria-label="Easy Apply filter." id="ember404" class="artdeco-pill artdeco-pill--slate artdeco-pill--2 artdeco-pill--choice ember-view search-reusables__filter-pill-button" type="button">  
<!---->        Easy Apply
      
</button>
  </div>
</li>

When I ran the following Python code, I could not find such an attribute. This is my Python code.
easy_apply_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@aria-label='Easy Apply filter.']")


This element has an id. why don't you use id instead of xpath?

@hero It might be randomly generated since it has a number, e.g. "ember404".

Have you checked to see if the element is in an IFRAME or shadow-root?

Can you share a URL that has an Easy Apply button? I'm looking through linkedin and couldn't find one quickly.

Somewhat ambiguous to decipher the issue with the given info; nonetheless as @JeffC stated, you may use ID, or the text of the button //button[normalize-space(text()= 'Easy Apply')] if you may want to, if it is not wrapped in iframe or is not shadow root as @JeffC mentioned.

Here's the URL, https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?currentJobId=3911668886&distance=25&geoId=102277331&keywords=Software%20Engineer&origin=JOBS_HOME_KEYWORD_HISTORY&refresh=true
I just did a search on Linkedln's jobs page with keywords and location. Also, when I did this //button[normalize-space(text()= 'Easy Apply')] ,it found multiple elements and I couldn't click on them.
